# If $M$ is a submanifold and $f$ has a local minimum at $x_0\in\partial M$, can we show $\frac{\partial f}{\partial\nu_{\partial M}}(x_0)\le0$?

Tags: differential-geometry, optimization, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

Let

- $d\in\mathbb N$;
- $k\in\{1,\ldots,d\}$;
- $M$ be a $k$-dimensional embedded $C^1$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$ with boundary;
- $\nu_{\partial M}$ denote the unit outer normal field on $\partial M$;
- $x_0\in M$;
- $T_{x_0}M$ denote the tangent space of $M$ at $x_0$;
- $f:M\to\mathbb R$ be $C^1$-differentiable at $x_0$;
- $T_{x_0}(f)$ denote the pushforward of $f$ at $x_0$.

> Assuming $x_0$ is a local minimum of $f$, how can we show that $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial\nu_{\partial M}}(x_0)\le0?\tag1$$
>
> **EDIT**: I guess, I was asking for too less and we can, more generally, show the following: If $v\in T_{x_0}M$, then $$\begin{cases}T_{x_0}(f)v\ge0&\text{, if }v\text{ is inward pointing};\\T_{x_0}(f)v\le0&\text{, if }v\text{ is outward pointing};\\T_{x_0}(f)v=0&\text{, if }v\text{ is inward pointing}.\end{cases}\tag2$$ Am I right? Can we show this?

I think $(2)$ should be relatively easy to obtain, but I need some help to justify a few subtleties.

Assume first that $v$ is inward pointing. Then there is (**the crucial thing is the form of the interval $I$ on which $\gamma$ is defined; why does $v$ being inward pointing imply that we can choose $I$ to be of the form $[0,\varepsilon)$?**) a $\varepsilon>0$ and a $C^1$-curve $\gamma:[0,\varepsilon)\to M$ with $\gamma(0)=x_0$ and $\gamma'(0)=v$. Since $x_0$ is a local minimum of $f$, we see that $0$ is a local minimum of $f\circ\gamma$. Now, if we were able to apply Lemma 1 below (**a possible problem being that $[0,\varepsilon)$ is clearly convex, but $\gamma$ is not chosen (but might can be) to be differentiable on a larger open set containing $[0,\varepsilon)$**), then we could immediatelly conclude that $$T_x(f)v=(f\circ\gamma)'(0)\ge0.\tag3$$

Analogously, if $v$ is outward pointing, the same should apply but with $[0,\varepsilon)$ replaced by $(-\varepsilon,0]$ (**again, I would like to know why we can choose $I$ to be of this particular form whenever $v$ is outward pointing**, but $(4)$ would now clearly yield $(f\circ\gamma)'(0)\le0$.

Most probably (**but I don't know how we need to argue for that**) we can take $I=(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ whenever $v\in T_{x_0}\partial M$. If that would be the case, then (since $I$ is open), we would clearly obtain $(f\circ\gamma)'(0)=0$.

---

**Lemma 1**: Let $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be open, $U\subseteq\Omega$ be convex, $x_\ast\in U$ and $g:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ be Fréchet differentiable at $x_\ast$. If $x_\ast$ is a local minimum of $\left.g\right|_U$, then $${\rm D}g(x_\ast)(x-x_\ast)\ge0.\tag4$$

Comment: The fact that if $\nu$ is an inward pointing tangent vector at $x_0 \in \partial M$ then one can find a smooth curve $\gamma \colon [0,\varepsilon) \rightarrow M$ with $\gamma(0) = x_0$ and $\gamma'(0) = \nu$ is usually taken to be the definition of "inward pointing" (see page 118 in Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds for instance). I'm sure that it will also be true with whatever definition you are working with. Your result then follows by carefully unwinding what it means to be $C^1$ when the domain is not an open interval and working with the one-sided derivative of $f \circ \gamma$.

Comment: And again, the fact that $\gamma$ (and $f \circ \gamma$) should be extended to a larger open set follows from the usual definitions of what it means for such functions to be "smooth" or "$C^1$".